# Internet stopped working Windows 10 guest (VirtualBox) on Ubuntu 20.04 host

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ubuntu-20.04

I updated my Windows 10 guest on my Ubuntu 20.04 host and suddenly lost internet connection on my Windows 10 virtual machine. Internet access is working fine on my host.

What I have tried:

- [Suggestions on this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43567695/access-virtualbox-mac-os-guest-on-windows-10-host-network)
- Disabling firewall on Windows 10
- Changing VirtualBox network adaptor
- Restarting Win10 guest

I can ping (8.8.8.8, for example) and I am getting a response.

I'm at a loss for what to try next. Any suggestions?

Comment: I updated my Windows 10 guest on my Ubuntu 20.04 host and suddenly lost internet connection on my Windows 10 virtual machine ............   Did you try resetting TCP/P and restarting the Windows 10 guest?

Comment: @John I just tried that and still experience the problem. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try making a different machine and see whether it is a problem with the guest or VBOX. Likely with the guest. Since TCP/IP reset did not work you may need to try a Windows 10 Repair

Comment: The guest works just fine before I update it to 20H2, that is when the internet connection breaks. Still recommend trying to install another Windows 10 guest and see what happens?

Comment: Yes that is what I would do first.  Seems easiest.